# Nil while appending data

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a type struct Course

```
struct Course {

let title: String
let subtitle: String
let instructor: String
let color: String

init(title: String, subtitle: String, instructor: String, color: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.instructor = instructor
    self.color = color
    }
}
```

This is my code trying to append the data of type struct Course into courses but end up getting nil error. What should I do?

```
var courses: [Course]!

courses?.append(Course(title: "Team-Based Mobile Device Application Development", subtitle: "2018SP INFOTC 4500/JOURN 4444 Moore & Musser", instructor: "", color: ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array. All you've do so far is declare it.

Change:

```
var courses: [Course]!
```

to:

```
var courses = [Course]()
```

This will declare and initialize `courses` as an empty array of `Course`.

Then:

```
courses?.append(Course...
```

becomes:

```
courses.append(Course...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize a variable before it used.
so need to change

```
var courses: [Course]!
courses?.append(Course(title: ...
```

to

```
var courses: [Course] = []
courses.append(Course(title: ...
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way for this to work is

```
var courses: [Course]! = []
```

with append function

```
courses.append(Course(title: "Team-Based Mobile Device Application Development", subtitle: "2018SP INFOTC 4500/JOURN 4444 Moore & Musser", instructor: "", color: ""))
```

Comment: No, this is not the best way. There is no need to declare it as an implicitly unwrapped optional using `!`. It makes no sense to do that on a line that initializes the array at the same time it is declared. The other two answers provide two equally good solutions. Both give the same result using two slightly different syntax options. You should accept one of the other two answers. Pick which ever one you prefer.